# Perl, Parsing a file based on column values

Tags: regex, perl

I want to parse a file that contain columns separated by **TAB**, I want to complete empty fields based on value of the **first** and **second** columns,

#### Input:

```
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    9:00    1    45.87    74
        10:00    99    167    42
        11:00    99    167.02    42
        12:00    167    167    42
        13:00    99    167    42
        14:00    167    167    42
    20-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
        1:00    99    167    42
        2:00    99    167.02    42
        3:00    167    167    42
        4:00    99    167    42
        5:00    167    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
        1:00    99    167    42
        2:00    99    167.02    42
        3:00    167    167    42
        4:00    99    167    42
        5:00    167    167    42
    20-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
        1:00    99    167    42
        2:00    99    167.02    42
        3:00    167    167    42
        4:00    99    167    42
        5:00    167    167    42
```

#### Expected Output:

```
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    9:00    1    45.87    74
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    10:00    99    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    11:00    99    167.02    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    12:00    167    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    13:00    99    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    19-12-20167    14:00    167    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    1:00    99    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    2:00    99    167.02    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    3:00    167    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    4:00    99    167    42
abcd/xyz/deft3    20-12-20167    5:00    167    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    1:00    99    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    2:00    99    167.02    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    3:00    167    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    4:00    99    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167    5:00    167    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    0:00    1    45.87    74
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    1:00    99    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    2:00    99    167.02    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    3:00    167    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    4:00    99    167    42
qerty/azer/uuui1    20-12-20167    5:00    167    167    42
```

#### This is my code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my @lines = split /\t/;
    my $name;

    next unless ( /^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\s+([0-9\_\-]+)\s+/ );

    $name = $3;

    print join( ",",
        $name = $1, $lines[0], $lines[1], $lines[2],
        $lines[3], $lines[4], $lines[5], $lines[6] )
            . "\n";
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: \Which lines do you need to complete? How are lines with `abcd/xyz/...` and those with `10:00 ...` used? Their format is different. The code doesn't explain this as it won't match any lines. Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the last full line of data.  Since you only need to remember a single value for each column, here's a solution that saves that one value each.  Depending on your needs, you may only need to save off values for the first two columns, so two scalars could do the same thing, but I'm not making that assumption here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @last_full_line;
while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\t/;

    # save off the old values for future use.
    for my $i (0..$#fields)
    {
        $last_full_line[$i] = $fields[$i] if length $fields[$i];
        $fields[$i] = $last_full_line[$i] unless length $fields[$i];
    }

    print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}


__END__
abcd/xyz/deft3  19-12-20167 9:00    1   45.87   74
                10:00   99  167 42
                11:00   99  167.02  42
                12:00   167 167 42
                13:00   99  167 42
                14:00   167 167 42
        20-12-20167 0:00    1   45.87   74
                1:00    99  167 42
                2:00    99  167.02  42
                3:00    167 167 42
                4:00    99  167 42
                5:00    167 167 42
qerty/azer/uuui1    19-12-20167 0:00    1   45.87   74
                1:00    99  167 42
                2:00    99  167.02  42
                3:00    167 167 42
                4:00    99  167 42
                5:00    167 167 42
        20-12-20167 0:00    1   45.87   74
                1:00    99  167 42
                2:00    99  167.02  42
                3:00    167 167 42
                4:00    99  167 42
        5:00    167 167 42
```